# Skip unit tests that take a long time

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I'm working with MS-Test for my unit tests writing.
most of my tests have a duration of less than 0.1 seconds.
I want to somehow tell VS "ignore the tests that take a long time to run when i'm running the tests manually, and when you run them on the build do not ignore them.

I know that in nunit there is an "explicit" attribute that will run the test only if you select him explicitly. I think that might help but not sure.

Help please

Comment: How long is 'a long time'? Can't you make the tests quicker? It's a lot better if you can run all your tests regularly and that each of them can be executed quickly. Otherwise, you'll probably forget to execute the ones which duration is too big

Comment: I know, but the tests are good and I want to somehow skip them by default when manually run test and let the server run them after check ins.

Comment: For example a good test that takes a long time is a build in caliburn check for PropertyChanged event raising that takes 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about this question in a language-agnostic, framework-agnostic manner yields that what you ask for is somewhat a conundrum:

The test tool will have no idea about the execution time of any of the unit tests until they are run; because this is dependant on not just the test tool and the tests themselves, but also on the application under test. The stop-gap solution to this would be to do things such as setting a time limit. If you do this, then that begs the question, when a test times out, should it be passed, failed, or perhaps fall into some other (third) category? ... Conundrum!

Thus to avoid this, I put forward that you should adopt a different strategy where you as the developer decide which subsets of the entire set of tests you wish to run in different situations. For example:

- A set of **smoke** tests;

  - i.e. tests that you would want to run first all of the time. If any of these fail then you don't want to bother executing any of the tests. Put only the really **fundamental** tests in this group.
- A **minimal** set of tests;

  - For your specific requirement this would be a set of tests containing all of the **"quick" or "fast"** tests, and you determine which ones they are.
- A **comprehensive** set of tests;

  - The tests which do not belong to any of the other categories. For your specific requirement this would be tests that are the **"slow" or "long"** ones.

When running your tests, you can then choose which of these subsets of tests to run, perhaps configuring it in some form of a script.

I use this approach to great effect in automated testing (integrated into a continuous integration system). I do this by having a script that, depending on the input parameters, would decide either to execute just the **smoke** tests plus the **minimal** tests; or alternatively the **smoke** tests, the **minimal** tests and the **comprehensive** tests (i.e. all of them).

HTH

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the information, I'm looking for more technical stuff, can you write some or put some links to your tools?

Comment: The specific tools I use are not going to be helpful for your, as they are non-Microsoft or Visual Studio. H/w just in case you are curious, they would be CruiseControl for continuous integration and JUnit/FEST as the test tools.
Come to think of it, you could probably do the same using CruiseControl.NET and any xUnit compatible test tool. HTH. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Timeout` attribute, and specify the timeout in milliseconds. If the timeout passes, the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like this

```
<TestMethod(), Timeout(1000)>
    Public Sub OutputWebservice_SubmitOutputJob_SubmitEmailJobHF001()
    End Sub
```

Comment: But i don't want the test to fail, I just want to skip it automatically on my client machine. The test is fine

Comment: it would be class as timeout not a failure

Comment: O.K but it is time consuming, lets say i got 1000 unit tests and 100 of them are long tests, and the timeout is 1 sec, so i'll burn 2 minutes for nothing? This 2 minutes will make developers to skip the run the unit test before the commit.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up the tests so they run on your server after the commit is made, then notify the developer (perhaps by email?) of any that fail.

This way the tests get run, regardless of their duration, but no programmer time is wasted.

Comment: I like your idea, but I want the developer to run some stuff before the commit